# Android: URLConnection.getContentLength() giving incorrect value

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, urlconnection, http-content-length

I'm trying to get the size of the contents of a URL using:

```
URLConnection conn = null;
URL url = null;
url = new URL("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/90210205/Default.html");
conn = url.openConnection();
conn.connect();
InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
int fileSize = conn.getContentLength();
System.out.println("File size " + fileSize);
while (in.read() != -1) {
    i++;
}
in.close();
System.out.println("Read " + i + " bytes of a possible " + fileSize);
```

I'm using this within the `doInBackground()` of an `AsyncTask` and for some reason `conn.getContentLength();` is returning `1273` when it should be returning `10136`.

I have used the above code within the Main of a regular Java application and `conn.getContentLength();` returns the correct 10136 value.

Why isn't it working in an `AsyncTask`?

Comment: Are you using  Chunked Transfer Encoding from your server side ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The description of `.getContentLength()` is that it returns the value of the `Content-Length` header field.  In ordinary circumstances, this should match the amount of data available to be read.  However...

(1) The header may not be present if chunked-encoding is being used to send the data.  In this case, `.getContentLength()` returns `-1` so that appears not to be the case here.

(2) By default, the implementation of `HttpURLConnection` requests that servers use gzip compression and it automatically decompresses the data for callers of `getInputStream()`. The Content-Encoding and Content-Length response headers are cleared in this case.

The last sentence seems to indicate that this also is not the case here, because you are not getting `-1` from .getContentLength()`, but the relative sizes (1273 / 10136) make me suspicious...

One test of this would be to disabled Gzip encoding by setting the acceptable encodings in the request header with:

```
urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "identity");
```

Another would be to 'snoop' the network traffic to observer the http headers and amount of data for clues.

BTW, `url.openStream()` is a convenience for `url.openConnection().getInputStream()`.